# What do i do to create a unit test for the code below

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public String getBloodPressureLevel() {

    if (this.systolic > MedicalRecord.AT_RISK_SYSTOLIC_UPPER_BOUND
            || this.diastolic > MedicalRecord.AT_RISK_DIASTOLIC_UPPER_BOUND) {
        return "High";
    } else if ((this.systolic >= MedicalRecord.AT_RISK_SYSTOLIC_LOWER_BOUND
            && this.systolic <= MedicalRecord.AT_RISK_SYSTOLIC_UPPER_BOUND)
            || (this.diastolic >= MedicalRecord.AT_RISK_DIASTOLIC_LOWER_BOUND
                    && this.diastolic <= MedicalRecord.AT_RISK_DIASTOLIC_UPPER_BOUND)) {
        return "At risk";
    } else {
        return "Normal";
    }
}
```

[Test cases i'm supposed to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0XJ4.png)

i'm just not sure how to go about this

Comment: What exactly is the question ?

Comment: i'm not sure how to write a j unit test for a method with a return value

Answer (score 3):

You start by reading a tutorial on how JUnit works, for example this [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html).

Then you think about the different *corners* of your production code, to then do things like

```
@Test
public void testForHigh() {
   YourClass underTest = new YourClass(/*systolic*/ 200, /*diastolic*/ 100);
   assertThat(underTest.getBloodPressureLevel(), is("High"));
}
```

( where `is()` is a hamcrest matcher, allowing to write more human readable test conditions and where I assume that you have some class that gets instantiated using a systolic and diastolic data point )

The real point here is: you have to research the tools you are supposed to use, and then you go and implement at least *one* method for each possible condition, representing the 11 different tests in your input.

( And no, I am not going to give you more code. The above is meant as inspiration to enable you to do this work yourself. )